# Why do we call Kotlin class as Java class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

The question is about this bulky expression `ClassName::class.java` that is being used when we want to use name of a class as a parameter of some method:

```
startActivity(Intent(this, TorchActivity::class.java))
```

In Java it would be just `ClassName.class` that is pretty and intuitive:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, TorchActivity.class))
```

But in Kotlin code I have to write `ClassName::class.java` even when `ClassName` is a Kotlin class. Am I doing something wrong? Is three any other way to call Kotlin classes?

Comment: *even when ClassName is a Kotlin class* that is exactly why you need class.java. startActivity is a java api that takes a java class as parameter. There is no kotlin api for this

Comment: A KClass and a Java Class are two distinct types. You need to pass the type that matches the method/function signature. `SomeJavaClass::class` is a KClass, because Kotlin tacks that on to Java objects that you call from Kotlin.